# receiving error 400 in yii framework

Tags: php, html, yii

What I have is an html form which i want to pass the data from it to the controller, where it performs a quick calculation and then it updates the database.

What I'm receiving is an error 400, I don't know why the request is invalid as I've set it up similar to the rest of the pages I'm using which work fine.

Below is the action in the controller and the view.

```
<?php
/* @var $this TokensController */
/* @var $model Tokens */

$this->breadcrumbs = array(
'Tokens' => array('index'),
$model->TokenID => 
'buy',
);
?>

<h1>Buy Tokens 
</h1>
<?php
 echo  'Your balance is ' .$model->TokenAmount;
 ?>

<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action = "buy">

 <input type='radio' name='qty' value='10' />10
 <input type='radio' name='qty' value='25' />25
 <input type='radio' name='qty' value='50' />50

</FORM>
```

Controller action

```
public function actionBuy($qty) {

    $_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    $model = Tokens::model()->findByAttributes(array('UserID' => $_id));
    if ($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, "Keep calm! If you havent bought tokens before this is normal");


    $this->render('buy', array(
        'model' => $model,));

   $qty = $_POST['qty'];
   echo $qty;
   $newtkamount = ($_model->TokenAmount + $qty);
   echo $qty . $newtkamount . $_model->TokenAmount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing $qty from the actionBuy Parameters

**public function actionBuy()**

or you can change it to

**public function actionBuy($qty = 0)**

Comment: Buy is already set their, last time I checked that if it's not in their you get a 403

Comment: and yea it's lower case for the first character

Comment: Then do one thing.. remove the $qty from the actionBuy Parameters

Comment: I remove that then it moans it's not defined as well as trying the array

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found that works was the set the parameter to `$qty = 0`.
The useing isset to confirm it is a post request